# Google Secret Manager: unable get value from secret manager with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

I am unable to get value from secret manager.

```
**Application.property:**
spring.secret.key=${sm://projects/154281748/secrets/serviceaccount/versions/1}

**bootstrap.property:**
spring.cloud.gcp.secretmanager.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gcp.secretmanager.secret-name-prefix=sm://

**pom.xml:**
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager</artifactId>             
</dependency>

**Java Code**
@Value("${spring.secret.key}")
private String key;
```

I am getting "//projects/154281748/secrets/serviceaccount/versions/1" value of Key.

Comment: Do you have an error? What's your credentials?

Comment: I don't have the secretmanager.versions.access permission, Is this the issue? I am using service account for service deployment. whom need this permission, Is this project level or default appengine service account

Comment: Where is running your app? How did you set up the credentials in the environment?

Comment: I have deployed app to App Engine. (How did you set up the credentials in the environment?)  Which credentials you are talking about?

Comment: In local machine I did the the credentials setup by:  GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\Users\username\Downloads\service-account-file.json"

Comment: Did you check if your App Engine default service account (if you use the default in your deployment) has the secret accessor role granted on it? In adition, can you tell me what's the content of your secret? I fear that's a services account key file (based on the name).

Comment: Yes, I have stored service account key in secret manager. I am not using Default App Engine  service account for deployment. I am using another service account for deployment. So Which service account need permission, Default AppEngine SA or Another service account.

Comment: Why do you need another service account? It does not make sense!

Comment: There are multiple user/developer and every developer having separate service account for deployment only, no one use default appEngine?   So Which service account need permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deployment and runtime are 2 different things. At deployment, user must have the permission to deploy a new service. You have 3 roles that you can find in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/roles)

At runtime, by default, the App Engine default service account is used. And, as you fill it, it's not a good practice because:

- The default role is Editor, that grant the service account too much permissions
- If you have 2 different services, both have the same permissions because they use the same identity (service account)

That's why, they have finally release a great feature: [user managed service account](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/user-managed-service-accounts)

You simply have to set the service account email in the `app.yaml` file, and that's all. You have a dedicated service account for your App Engine service.

---

Now you have the identity that you want at runtime. At runtime, you want to get a secret. So, you must grant the runtime identity to be able to access the secret.

**HOWEVER**, because you already have a specific and dedicated identity for your App Engine service, loading a service account key file from secret manager makes no sense! Use directly the runtime identity!